# What is the best way to continually query the server making constant GET requests?

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is my JSON Object

```
{ 
  "services": [ 
  { 
      "name": "Our Test Service", 
      "authCode": 981846 
  }, 
  { 
      "name": "BuckeyeLink", 
      "authCode": 272860 
  }] 
}
```

I have the link to the part of the website I want to continually do GET requests asking for this specific information, but my question is what is the best way to do this?

Shoudl I just make an infinite loop that is constantly querying the server? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: yes, cloud messaging... example: firebase

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop would not be useful (and never is). What you want is use a Handler and a Runnable together in a stepped fashion (say, every few seconds). In your activity you could define a handler as private member, then a couple of methods such as `pollForData` and `cancelPolling` (because eventually, you might no longer be interested in polling for changes to the data, and you should cancel that to be kind to the device's battery/performance).

As an example, a simple activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "YourActivity";
    private long retryInterval = 3000; // 3 seconds
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.your_layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // when the activity starts, start/resume polling
        super.onResume();
        pollForData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // when the activity is paused, also pause the polling
        super.onPause();
        cancelPolling();
    }

    private void pollForData() {
        // I'm a bit heavy on the null checks...

        if(runnable != null) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Runnable executing");

                    // do the thing that fetches the data
                    getData();

                    // repost this runnable on the interval we defined
                    handler.postDelayed(this, retryInterval);
                }
            };

            // post the first runnable to start the chain
            handler.postDelayed(r, retryInterval);
        }
    }

    private void cancelPolling() {
        // cancel all runnable callbacks for the handler; we're gtg
        if(handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
    }

    private void getData() {
        // your code to fetch your JSON data from a url
    }
}
```